# Specifying variable in CoefficientRules

Tags: coefficients, notation

I am trying to determine the number of terms in an expression, but I have created a matrix to represent variables:

```
xMat = Table[sGain[[i, 1]] + 4, {i, 1, 3}]
```

Where `sGain` is my representative variable. I need to count the number of terms at each position in `xMat`, but using

```
Table[CoefficientRules[xMat[[i]]], {i, 1, 3}]
```

it uses `sGain` as a coefficient and doesn't count the `1/sGain` part as a term. In functions like `Solve` I can specify the variable. Is there some way to do that here?

Comment: Can you give us `sGain`, or at least a way to generate something similar?

Comment: You could say sGain is a zero matrix (actually for what I provided just an array), but sGain[[1,1]]=s, where s is a variable. I'm trying to avoid allowing Mathematica to factor future expressions involving xMat.

Comment: To clarify further, I want the output to be: 
{{{-1}->1,{0}->4},{{-1}->1,{0}->4},{{-1}->1,{0}->4}}
so that I can see the coefficients of all the terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I can be a bit more general: Suppose you've got an expression of the form

```
expr = Array[a, 5, -2].Array[s^# &, 5, -2]
```

> $$\frac{a(-2)}{s^2} + \frac{a(-1)}{s} + a(1) s+a(0)+a(2) s^2$$

Then `CoefficentRules` will fail since it only works on polynomials (ie, no negative powers). You *could* mess around to try and use `CoefficientRules`, but it would probably be easier to use `Exponent` and `Coefficient`.

```
Exponent[expr, s, List]

(* {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2} *)
```

gives a list of the powers of `s` in `expr`, and

```
Coefficient[expr, s, #] & /@ Exponent[expr, s, List]

(* {a[-2], a[-1], a[0], a[1], a[2]} *)
```

gives the coefficients for each of those powers. If you want the same output you'd get from `CoefficientRules` you can use

```
{#} -> Coefficient[expr, s, #] & /@ Exponent[expr, s, List]

(* {{-2} -> a[-2], {-1} -> a[-1], {0} -> a[0], {1} -> a[1], {2} -> a[2]} *)
```

You can put this in a function as

```
npCoefficientRules[nonpoly_, var_] := 
  {#} -> Coefficient[nonpoly, var, #] & /@ Exponent[nonpoly, var, List]
```

(Note that this won't work as is if you have more than one variable, say `s` and `t`.)

If your expressions *only* involve negative powers of `s`, then you could use `CoefficientRules` by specifying the variable as `s^-1`. Or if you have positive and negative powers you *could* multiply through by some power of `s`. But they both seem like horrible options to me:

```
sGain = ConstantArray[1/s, 3];
xMat = Table[sGain[[i]] + 4, {i, 1, 3}];
Table[CoefficientRules[xMat[[i]], s^-1], {i, 1, 3}]
Table[CoefficientRules[s xMat[[i]], s], {i, 1, 3}]

(* {{{1} -> 1, {0} -> 4}, {{1} -> 1, {0} -> 4}, {{1} -> 1, {0} -> 4}} 
   {{{1} -> 4, {0} -> 1}, {{1} -> 4, {0} -> 1}, {{1} -> 4, {0} -> 1}} *)
```

With `npCoefficientRules`

```
npCoefficientRules[#, s] & /@ xMat

(* {{{-1} -> 1, {0} -> 4}, {{-1} -> 1, {0} -> 4}, {{-1} -> 1, {0} -> 4}} *)
```

For a little extra convenience, you can make `npCoefficientRules` `Listable`

```
SetAttributes[npCoefficientRules, Listable];
```

Then

```
npCoefficientRules[xMat, s]
```

returns the same thing.

(If you are in fact "trying to determine the number of terms in an expression", you could just use `Length`; `Length /@ xMat` returns `{2, 2, 2}`. You'd have to be careful about how your expressions are represented, but `Collect` or `Simplify` should help there.)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I did try using a combination of Collect and CoefficientRules, but I am unable to determine the order which I will not know. Your function solves the issue, though.

Comment: @Haff Glad it helped. Don't forget you can upvote answers and accept an answer if you feel it has adequately answered your question. That's _not_ a hint -- you are welcome to leave your question open if you're looking for a better answer. But look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, yesterday it would not let me. Looks like 
 StackExchange recognizes me as not a machine now.